# NullSpace[_, Method->"OneStepRowReduction"] is sometimes wrong; how can I work out when this happens?

Tags: linear-algebra, bugs, version-8, version-7

*Edit 2015: Has this been fixed yet?*

---

(This is on MMA 7.0.1.0 on OS X)

I've just found a large matrix `m` for which `NullSpace[m]` and `NullSpace[m, Method->"OneStepRowReduction"]` give different answers (the first one is the correct answer).

I put the matrix up at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=fTev0uKZ) as won't fit here!

What's going on? How might I guess ahead of time which arguments are going to break `Method->"OneStepRowReduction"`?

(Update; it seems the bug has got *worse* in 8, rather than better.)

Comment: On a side note, Mathematica 8 yields an empty list in both cases. I'm going to assume the bug has been fixed.

Comment: Could have been either of two bugs in "OneStepRowReduction" when algebraics are present. Both were fixed prior to version 8 release.

Comment: No, I think this is a real problem --- and your answers indicate it's got worse in Mathematica 8, not better! The NullSpace should not be empty. Here's the result of RootReduce[NullSpace[m]]: {{Root[3 - 80 #1^2 + 9 #1^4 &, 1], Root[3 - 80 #1^2 + 9 #1^4 &, 4], 
  Root[-3 + 4 #1^2 + 3 #1^4 &, 4], Root[3 - 32 #1^2 + 81 #1^4 &, 3], 
  Root[1 - 38 #1 + 116 #1^2 - 90 #1^3 + 27 #1^4 &, 4], 
  Root[1 + 38 #1 + 116 #1^2 + 90 #1^3 + 27 #1^4 &, 4], 
  Root[-1 + 23 #1^2 + 27 #1^4 &, 3], 1}}, which you can verify really is in the kernel.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, is there any reference for these bugs? I'd like to be able to ascertain which code running in 7 I can or cannot 'trust' (to the extend that trusting Mathematica is ever possible).

Comment: @Scott Morrison (1) No reference I'm aware of. (2) I verified that matrix.your_vector has a 97th component of around -10.8. So it's not a serious contender for a null vector.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this Daniel. In MMA 7 RootReduce was verifying that m.v was exactly zero; so perhaps the problem is in RootReduce in either 7 or 8? I'll investigate further.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard for me, versions 7.0.1 and 9.0.1 (Windows) both give an empty null space. It is possible that this was a Mac OS-specific numerical bug.

Comment: @Oleksandr Thanks working to pin this down.

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version    
(*  "10.4.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)"  *)
```

Let `m = <pastebin monster>`.

```
ns1 = NullSpace[m];
ns2 = NullSpace[m, Method -> "OneStepRowReduction"];
diff = ns1 - ns2;
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
RootReduce[diff]
(*  {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}  *)
```

So they're equivalent in V10.4.1.

*Update: Checking correctness*

After many minutes, this returns the zero vector:

```
m.First@ns1 // RootReduce
```

And these all return a rank of `7`:

```
MatrixRank[m]
MatrixRank[N[m]]
MatrixRank[N[m, 32]]
```

Finally, `Dimensions[m]` yields `{880, 8}`, all of which confirms the answer is correct.

Comment: Does the output appear to be correct or could they both be wrong?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It appears (numerically) to give a correct null space member and the matrix rank comes out to be 7 (for an 880 x 8 matrix), both on the exact matrix and on numericized matrices at various precisions.  So yes, the output appears to be correct. (I'm waiting on `m.First@ns1 // RootReduce`, but I'm not sure it will finished any time soon, or that I will wait for it.)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this problem (fed the matrix into an object called m) with 10.3 on a Macbook pro running OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite). Both methods yield an empty Nullspace, though onesteprowreduction took much longer.  So it looks like it hasn't been fixed in 10.3 :(.

Another possibility remains.  @scott-morrison - can you demonstrate that it really is in the kernel?

In[17]:= NullSpace[m]

Out[17]= {}

In[18]:= NullSpace[m, Method -> "OneStepRowReduction"]

Out[18]= {}

Comment: This answer might be more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: True, but I lack the reputation to be able to comment on others' questions